# UIDatePicker date picking problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to show start date and end date in date picker and select them to perform some event in iPhone

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
// Get the current date  
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];

NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];

// Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
// Notification will fire in one minute
[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. The above code doesn't accomplish anything other than `NSDate *itemDate = [self.datePicker date];`. You just break the picker date down into components and then reassemble them.

Comment: I want that in date picker i may be able to select start and end date how to display start and date

Comment: You either need two pickers, or another control elsewhere on the screen that indicates if you are currently picking the start date or the end date. You can't pick two dates at once with the same picker unless you have a customised pickerView, but it would be very cramped.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a UITableView with two rows, one for the start and one for the end date. Then in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath you set the datePicker.tag to the indexPath.row. When reveicing UIControlEventValueChanged you can simpy get the NSDate from the UIDatePicker and assign it to your variable.